# Problem with null in SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, null

```
select 
    case 
       when ''!='abcd'
           then 'nodate'
       else 'date'
    end;
```

Here I hope `''` stand for null, but when I execute this query I am getting `'date'` as an ouput, rather than `'nodate'`. What is the problem in this query? Why does `''!='abcd'` condition checking become true?

Comment: you have problem in your problen

Comment: hi webarto.. what is problen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at comments for this answer, here is the explaination -

In your example, `''` is considered as `NULL` in Oracle and hence `'' != 'abcd'` is evaluated to `UNKNOWN`, which is the reason the 'else clause' result is returned (and not the 'when clause' result).

If you want to check some column for `NULL` explicitly mention it.

```
...case when columnName is NULL then ... else ... end
```

or if you are checking for some column value to be `'abcd'` then use -

```
...case when columnName != 'abcd' then ... else ... end
```

Comment: sachin could u please look at the my query again?i updated now. as per your ans the condition is true, then it should return'nodate' right.why its returing 'date'?

Comment: Actually, in Oracle `''` is the same as `NULL`.  However, an equality test doesn't work for NULL:  `NULL = NULL` would not be true.  So you do need to use `IS NULL` to test if a value is NULL.

Comment: -1 because your first four sentences are false. Oracle doesn't know the difference between the empty string and NULL: they are both considered NULL.

Comment: thanks DAVE for your help.in my PL/SQL program i jus declared a variable as l_variable varchar(20); In later part of my program i used this variable to compare with a string... if l_variable != 'abcd' then statements; end if; according to the condition the program should go inside the if loop but thats not happening in my case... any how your comments gave be better idea.

Comment: @Dave Costa, @Rob van Wijk - Even if `''` means `NULL` why would it evaluate to false condition? The OP is checking for `NULL != 'abcd'`. Shouldn't this be TRUE always?

Comment: @Sachin: `NULL != 'abcd'` should evalute to `NULL` in all decent rdbms systems, Oracle included...

Comment: @Sachin:  Because `NULL` never produces TRUE in any comparison except IS NULL.  NULL indicates an unknown value, so both `NULL = x` and `NULL != x` are considered unknown conditions, regardless of the value of x.

Comment: @ypercude,@Dave Costa - Thanks guys, Good, this is something I learned new today, no wonder I love SO. Edited my answer based on your comments. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want check for NULL, try this:

`value IS NULL`

So, if you want to replace `''` with `NULL`, don't put `NULL != 'abcd'` but:

`'abcd' IS NOT NULL`

---

if there is a variable there and not `''`, try:

```
IF (l_variable != 'abcd) or (l_variable IS NULL)
```

It would be better however, to post complete code and not a modified part of it.

Answer (score 0):

use NULL to check if the value is NULL, also see http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_case_statement_else_null_value.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

case when YourColumn is null then 'nodate' else 'yes date' end

Comment: in my PL/SQL program i jus declared a variable as l_variable varchar(20); In later part of my program i used this variable to compare with a string... if l_variable != 'abcd' then statements; end if; according to the condition the program should go inside the if loop but thats not happening in my case.

Comment: Try: `IF (l_variable != 'abcd) or (l_variable IS NULL)`